# how to sort with mongodb php

Tags: php, mongodb

I've tried a number of variations to get mongodb php to sort by score decending. It won't do it.

here's my script

```
  $dd=array('gameID'=>(int)$gameID);
  $s=array( 'score' => -1);
  $cursor = $collectiontsWon->find($dd)->sort($s)->limit(7)->skip(0);
```

Everything is right, this is like the 8 variation of sort I've used. But it's NOT sorting by score decending on my site. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a sample document? Also have you tried querying directly via the CLI?

Comment: I had a screen shot and link but that got deleted

Comment: I saw that but it did not contain any useful information for your problem nor a sample document from your database. It would be useful to present one of those mongodb documents you are trying to sort and see if we can spot any error with it. Also what about the CLI I asked about?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the cursor, then sorting the data

```
$cursor = $mongo->collection->find()->limit(7);

$cursor = $cursor->sort(array("score" => -1));
foreach($cursor as $doc) {
    // Do something...
}
```

Also, I don't think you need to explicitly set skip to 0.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php`

`$cursor->sort(array('x' => 1));` // Sort on field x, ascending

**// The order in the associative array is important. For instance, these two
// examples will yield different results:**

`$cursor->sort(array('date' => 1, 'age' => -1));` // Sort on date ascending and age descending

`$cursor->sort(array('age' => -1, 'date' => 1));` // Sort on age descending and date ascending

`?>`